# buttonOnClick switch isn't working

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

One of the activities in my app has three buttons in it and I used a switch to code them. I've used nearly identical code several other times in my app, but this particular one doesn't work. When I navigate to this screen and click any of the three buttons, nothing happens.

Here's the code that isn't working:

```
public void buttonOnClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.generalPrefabButton:
                Intent generalPrefabScreen = new Intent();
                generalPrefabScreen.setClass(this, General_Prefab_Order.class);
                startActivity(generalPrefabScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.conduitBendButton:
                Intent conduitBendScreen = new Intent();
                conduitBendScreen.setClass(this, Conduit_Bend_Order.class);
                startActivity(conduitBendScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.safetyReportButton:
                Intent safetyReportScreen = new Intent();
                safetyReportScreen.setClass(this, Safety_Report.class);
                startActivity(safetyReportScreen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add your xml file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button button = new Button(R.id.generalPrefabButton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This sets the onClickListener activating the action in the onClick method.

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is to make your class implement `OnClickListener` and then add it to your buttons like this:

Example:

```
//make your class implement OnClickListener     
public class MyClass implements OnClickListener{ ... //Create your buttons and set their onClickListener to "this"    

Button generalPrefabButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonplay);   
generalPrefabButton.setOnClickListener(this);

Button conduitBendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop); 
conduitBendButton.setOnClickListener(this); ... 

//implement the onClick method here 
public void onClick(View v) { 
// Perform action on click 
switch(v.getId()) { 

case R.id.generalPrefabButton:
Intent generalPrefabScreen = new Intent(); 
generalPrefabScreen.setClass(this, General_Prefab_Order.class); 
startActivity(generalPrefabScreen);
break;

case R.id.conduitBendButton: 
Intent conduitBendScreen = new Intent();
conduitBendScreen.setClass(this, Conduit_Bend_Order.class); 
startActivity(conduitBendScreen); 
break;

case R.id.safetyReportButton:
Intent safetyReportScreen = new Intent(); 
safetyReportScreen.setClass(this, Safety_Report.class); 
startActivity(safetyReportScreen);
break;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your Buttons in the layout .xml file:
**android:onClick="buttonOnClick"**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```